# QEMU over ssh without using vncviewer

Tags: bash, qemu, vnc

It seems that when I want to run `qemu-system-x86_64` on a node via `ssh -Y`, I have to connect to the guest via VNC. So, here is an example:

```
[mahmood@rocks7 ~] ssh -Y compute-0-0
[mahmood@compute-0-0 ~] qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -hda win7_x64_snap.img -boot c -usbdevice tablet -enable-kvm -device e1000,netdev=host_files -netdev user,net=10.0.2.0/24,id=host_files,restrict=off
qemu-sqemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature:    CPUID.80000001H:ECX.tbm [bit 21]
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
```

As you can see, although I haven't specified `vnc` option for qemu, it shows a message that I have to connect via vnc.

Is there any way to directly bring up the guest window? If I run that command on the main node (without ssh), then the guest window is shown quickly.

Comment: Can you move your 2nd question, to a separate question. We have a one question per question policy. Doing this will allow some one with one of the answers to answer.

Comment: Done. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492656