# Getting the last sentence of a running program from stdout/stderr

Tags: bash

When I run a `qemu` command, I see a message at the bottom line which is giving me an IP:PORT for vncviewer command.

```
[mahmood@com[mahmood@compute-0-0 ~] qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -hda win7_x64_snap.img -boot c -usbdevice tablet -enable-kvm -device e1000,netdev=host_files -netdev user,net=10.0.2.0/24,id=host_files,restrict=off
qemu-sqemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature:    CPUID.80000001H:ECX.tbm [bit 21]
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
```

How can I get the last line which is printed in the screen?, so I have extract the last part which is `127.0.0.1:5900`.

Comment: The `qemu` is a long running process. Do you need the host:port in another script?

Comment: Yes. The program is running and I want to get the IP:PORT to use in another script to connect.

Comment: Does this help: `netstat -tnp 2>/dev/null | grep qemu-system-x86_64 | sed "s/ \+/ /g"  | cut -d' ' -f 4`. I don't have qemu to test.

Comment: netstat command usually needs root access.

Comment: Well, you just want to see your own ports and processes. Or does qemu run as root?

Comment: OK. `netstat -tnp | grep qemu` returns nothing. However, `netstat -tulpn | grep qemu` returns the appropriate output which is showing that qemu is listening on loclahost:5900. It works even with non root user. I will go for the next parts. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Mahmood, do you have an XML config file that enables the VNC option? I don't see it in the command you wrote.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: Good point. The issue has been asked in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492652

Comment: @mahmood glad you found the solution, but could you please post it as an answer instead of editing into the question?

Comment: Since the question ends up being fairly specific to qemu and VNC, I'd like to suggest that the title is updated to reflect that; otherwise, generic "last line of output" questions *would* be answered with the `tail`-type answers we have here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: To be honest, I posted two questions in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492652 where the first was related to qemu and ssh and the second was related to qemu and vnc and if you see the comment, I decided to post the second as a general question about catching the last sentence on the screen from a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since qemu is a long running program and it doesn't return back to the prompt, it is easier to open another terminal and check which IP:PORT the qemu is using. So, the command is

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep qemu-system | awk '{print $4}'
127.0.0.1:5900
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `tail` and `sed`, or just `sed`

e.g.

```
address=$(the_above_command | sed -r -e 's/VNC server running on ([0-9.:]+)$/\1/')
echo "$address" #or some other command
```

Test the bit in the `()` to see that it give what you want.
The `$(cmd)` is a substitution, it takes the stdout of `cmd`, and replaces itself with this output. The line is then re-parsed.

Note: if program is running/continuing to run, then you can not know if the current line is the last line. Luckily I don't think you have to know, that it is the last line.

Comment: Fortunately that is the last line. However, the first line causes the program to run and I don't see any vnc message (the list line is disappeared). Moreover, the program continues to run and I don't see the prompt in order to echo or something else.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `grep` and `cut` would be useful here.

You can extract the last line with

```
grep -m1 'VNC server running on'
```

The `-m1` flag will mean grep will stop reading after the first match, since this is presumably a long running process.

You could then cut out the address with

```
cut -d' ' -f5
```

If you're looking to pipe the output into another process, you will probably want to start `qemu` in the background like so:

```
(qemu-system-x86_64... &) | grep -m1 'VNC server running on' | cut -d' ' -f5
```

Comment: Running that command doesn't show the `VNC` line. So, I can not put it in a variable.

Comment: The `qemu-system-x86_64...` is meant as a substitution for your command. What part doesn't "show the `VNC` line"?

Comment: See the picture at https://pasteboard.co/HV2Q1Fx.png

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grep -m1 -oP '(\d{1,3}\.?){4}:\d{1,5}' <( your-qemu-command 2>&1 )
```

- `<( your-qemu-command 2>&1 )` is a process substitution that launches `qemu` with stdout/stderr redirected into an anonymous pipe or FIFO;
- `grep` reads from the pipe/FIFO, roughly looking for the pattern IP:PORT, with IP refering to an IPv4 address. The `-o` option to `grep` ensures that it will only print the IP:PORT combination of a matching line; the `-m1` option ensures that `grep` will return to the prompt once it has found what it was looking for (i.e. exit on first match). The `-P` option indicates use of Perl regular expression syntax.
- note that `qemu` remains running in the background until it finishes. Any output on stdout/stderr by `qemu` after termination of the `grep` command is lost, but since the IP:PORT combination is supposed to be the last output, this should be of no concern.

If you want to capture the output of the above command, simply wrap it in a command substitution `$(...)` like so:

```
ip_port=$( grep ...etc )
```

Comment: Although I have updated the post, regarding you command, I have to say that it does print "VNC server is running on 127.0.0.1:5900" and the IP:PORT is shown in red. However, since the command doesn't return to the prompt, it is not possible to catch the IP:PORT.

Comment: @mahmood Did you run the grep command with both the `-m1` and the `-oP` options? Initially, I accidentally left them out from my answer.

Comment: @mahmood I don't have qemu available on my system, but if I emulate the qemu process with a long-running script with similar output, it works.